# Trying to use qtdesigner instead of manually creating gui all the time. having trouble getting started with a listview

Tags: python, pyqt, qt-designer

I am struggling with something I think is simple but just don't see it.

I am trying to start using qtdesigner for my gui design and maintenance but I have issues working out how to access them from the output of qtdesigner.  I have run them through pyuic5.exe and generated Python code from the xml of designer and setup an app.py to import that into to run my code from.

here is the app.py:

```
import sys
from PyQt5 import QtGui
from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel

from PyQt5.QtWidgets import (
    QApplication, QDialog, QMainWindow, QMessageBox, QListView
)

from PyQt5.QtSql import (
    QSqlDatabase, QSqlDriver, QSqlQuery
)

import PyQt5.QtCore

from PyQt5.uic import loadUi

from main_window_ui import Ui_MainWindow

class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.connectSignalsSlots()
        updateTemplateList()
    def connectSignalsSlots(self):
        self.action_Exit.triggered.connect(self.close)
        #self.action_About.triggered.connect(self.about)

def updateTemplateList():
    model = QStandardItemModel()
    listView.setModel(model)

    entries = ['one','two', 'three']

    for i in entries:
        item = QStandardItem(i)
        model.appendRow(item)

    model.layoutChanged.emit()

def checkDB():
    # Try to open the connection and handle possible errors
    if not con.open():
        QMessageBox.critical(
            None,
            "App Name - Error!",
            "Database Error: %s" % con.lastError().databaseText(),
        )
        sys.exit(1)

if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    checkDB()
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

the designer output after run through pyui5.exe is:

```
# -*- coding: utf-8 -*-

# Form implementation generated from reading ui file '.\ui\main_window_ui.ui'
#
# Created by: PyQt5 UI code generator 5.15.4
#
# WARNING: Any manual changes made to this file will be lost when pyuic5 is
# run again.  Do not edit this file unless you know what you are doing.


from PyQt5 import QtCore, QtGui, QtWidgets


class Ui_MainWindow(object):
    def setupUi(self, MainWindow):
        MainWindow.setObjectName("MainWindow")
        MainWindow.resize(309, 652)
        self.centralwidget = QtWidgets.QWidget(MainWindow)
        self.centralwidget.setObjectName("centralwidget")
        self.listView = QtWidgets.QListView(self.centralwidget)
        self.listView.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 40, 291, 521))
        self.listView.setObjectName("listView")
        self.pushButton = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(10, 570, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton.setObjectName("pushButton")
        self.pushButton_2 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_2.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(210, 570, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_2.setObjectName("pushButton_2")
        self.pushButton_3 = QtWidgets.QPushButton(self.centralwidget)
        self.pushButton_3.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(110, 570, 93, 28))
        self.pushButton_3.setObjectName("pushButton_3")
        self.label = QtWidgets.QLabel(self.centralwidget)
        self.label.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(60, 10, 211, 16))
        font = QtGui.QFont()
        font.setPointSize(11)
        self.label.setFont(font)
        self.label.setObjectName("label")
        MainWindow.setCentralWidget(self.centralwidget)
        self.menubar = QtWidgets.QMenuBar(MainWindow)
        self.menubar.setGeometry(QtCore.QRect(0, 0, 309, 26))
        self.menubar.setObjectName("menubar")
        self.menu_file = QtWidgets.QMenu(self.menubar)
        self.menu_file.setObjectName("menu_file")
        MainWindow.setMenuBar(self.menubar)
        self.statusbar = QtWidgets.QStatusBar(MainWindow)
        self.statusbar.setObjectName("statusbar")
        MainWindow.setStatusBar(self.statusbar)
        self.action_Exit = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.action_Exit.setObjectName("action_Exit")
        self.actionAbout = QtWidgets.QAction(MainWindow)
        self.actionAbout.setObjectName("actionAbout")
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.action_Exit)
        self.menu_file.addAction(self.actionAbout)
        self.menubar.addAction(self.menu_file.menuAction())

        self.retranslateUi(MainWindow)
        QtCore.QMetaObject.connectSlotsByName(MainWindow)

    def retranslateUi(self, MainWindow):
        _translate = QtCore.QCoreApplication.translate
        MainWindow.setWindowTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "MainWindow"))
        self.pushButton.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Edit"))
        self.pushButton_2.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Delete"))
        self.pushButton_3.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Add"))
        self.label.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "Job Data for instructions"))
        self.menu_file.setTitle(_translate("MainWindow", "&File"))
        self.action_Exit.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "&Exit"))
        self.actionAbout.setText(_translate("MainWindow", "About"))
```

I am trying to update the listview in here with the updateTemplateList() and can not seem to get there.

thank you in advance for any help :-)

Answer (score 1, accepted):

The main error is that you are referencing non-existent objects, for example listView has not been created and is different from the listView attribute of `Ui_MainWindow` that must be referenced through the instance.

```py
import sys

from PyQt5.QtGui import QStandardItem, QStandardItemModel
from PyQt5.QtWidgets import QApplication, QMainWindow, QListView

from main_window_ui import Ui_MainWindow


class Window(QMainWindow, Ui_MainWindow):
    def __init__(self, parent=None):
        super().__init__(parent)
        self.setupUi(self)
        self.model = QStandardItemModel()
        self.listView.setModel(self.model)
        self.connectSignalsSlots()
        self.updateTemplateList()

    def connectSignalsSlots(self):
        self.action_Exit.triggered.connect(self.close)
        # self.action_About.triggered.connect(self.about)

    def updateTemplateList(self):
        entries = ["one", "two", "three"]
        for i in entries:
            item = QStandardItem(i)
            self.model.appendRow(item)


if __name__ == "__main__":
    app = QApplication(sys.argv)
    win = Window()
    win.show()
    sys.exit(app.exec())
```

<sub>Recommendation: Review your OOP notes, especially the concepts of inheritance, instance, etc.</sub>

Comment: Hi and thanks for having a look.  Yes I have tried every combination I can think of to access the instance that is created when importing the main_window_ui.py that was generated from the qtdesigner app and am sure I have had it right but does not.... I am going to go look at something else for a bit and come back to this later just would love to know what it thinks the correct instance is I should be using to access it...

Comment: @JustinCarlson the problem with your code has nothing to do with the way you try to access the UI (except for the fact that there's no `listView`), unless you're trying to access UI elements using the *class* (instead of the *instance*) or you're creating a *new* instance everytime you try to access them. As eyllanesc already pointed out, do some research on *very important aspects* of OOP like classes, instances, inheritance and methods. Compare your code to his, and try to understand the differences, which are *very* important.

Comment: Wow, I don't know what I was doing the other day but yeah that makes way more sense today :-) thank you for all your help!